# Terraform outs from a resource called via a for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, foreach, terraform, subnet

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with the following I have a base resource to create aws subnets

```
resource aws_subnet subnet {
  vpc_id     = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block = var.cidr_block
}

output subnetId {
 value = aws_subnet.subnet.id
}

module private_subnet {
   source = "linktoresourcedetailedabove"
   for_each = var.privateSubnet
   vpd.id   = var.vpc_id
   cidr_block = each.value.cidr_block
}
```

I have a module which calls using a for_each loop based on a var based in, my question is this resource might be called 10 times and I want to store each id and then access this from another module but I seem to be hitting issues here, I tried updating `aws_subnet.subnet.id` `to aws_subnet.subnet.*.id` but am still not having anyluck and can't seem to find anything out there that can help me.

Comment: Can you provide example code of how you use the 10 times a module?

Comment: sure, added that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `private_subnet` modules has output

```
output subnetId {
 value = aws_subnet.subnet.id
}
```

then once you create your `private_subnet` modules, you can get the list of all `subnetId` creates as:

```
values(module.private_subnet)[*].subnetId
```